# How do I return a result from a function in Python

Tags: python

How do I get the returned result from the below function?

```
def various_return_types(n):
    if(n==1):
        return True              
    else:
        return False 

various_return_types(1)
```

Comment: I don't why your function shouldn't return anything, but you are not printing the result. And BTW: how about `return n == 1`?

Comment: When you're running python code from a file it won't print out any output unless you specify `print True`. If you are using the python console/command line, then it will print out your results

Comment: What is with the `if/else` block at the bottom?  It contains several errors, so this code can't even run as it is.

Answer (score 1):

The function call does return a value but since you are not assigning it to a variable, you can't use it.

If you use

```
ret = various_return_types(1)
```

then, `ret` will contain the boolean value you can check.